# How to retrieve milliseconds from Date type in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to do a simple app and since I'm a beginner I'm struggling to retrieve the date saved in my mongoose schema and transform it to milliseconds.

First, in my front-end I would like to save the date from the input: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ3Km.png)

This is how it is saved in my database: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYep5.png)
Format: 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00

I would like to have this as milliseconds when I return to my front-end to calculate the months. If I change the data type to "Number" it works. However, I cannot insert date type anymore from the input.

This is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const EmployeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  employeeName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  employeeShift: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  employeeStartDay: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
});

const Employee = mongoose.model("Employee", EmployeeSchema);
module.exports = Employee;
```

My frontend:

```
{employeeList.map((val, key) => {
        const month = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
        const startDate = val.employeeStartDay;
        const finalDate = date.getTime();

        const months = Math.floor(-(startDate - finalDate) / month);
        const workingDaysToBeUsed = Math.floor(months * 1.166);

        return (
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>Specialist</th>
                <th>Schedule</th>
                <th>Start Day</th>
                <th>months passed</th> {/*months passed*/}
                <th>Days used</th>
                <th>Days accumulated</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>{val.employeeName}</td>
                <td>{val.employeeShift}</td>
                <td>{startDate}</td>
                <td>{months}</td>
                <td>{}</td>
                <td>{workingDaysToBeUsed}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

If I try to startDate.getTime() I receive an error message of startDate.getTime is not a function and this is what I don't understand.

I will appreciate some help.

Comment: Check the typeof for that field before calling getTime.  If you want milliseconds since epoch, you might use startDate.valueOf(), but that also will only work if startDate is a Date().

Comment: Thank you. However, valueOf() returns the exact same format "2021-03-23T00:00:00.000Z" and if I try to getTime() I still see the error "is not a function".

Comment: I could find the solution.

Basically, I had to check the typeof startDate and then transform the string to object to use the function getTime().

so const d = new Date(startDate)
const time = d.getTime()